# Matrix Vector Product across Multiple Dimensions

Tags: numpy, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, numpy-einsum

I have two arrays:

```
A = torch.rand((64, 128, 10, 10))
B = torch.rand((64, 128, 10))
```

I would like to compute the product, represented by C, where we do a matrix-vector multiplication across the first and second dimensions of A and B, so:

```
# C should have shape: (64, 128, 10)
for i in range(0, 64):
   for j in range(0, 128):
       C[i,j] = torch.matmul(A[i,j], B[i,j])
```

Does anyone know how to do this using `torch.einsum`? I tried the following, but I am getting an incorrect result.

```
C = torch.einsum('ijkl, ijk -> ijk', A, B)
```

Comment: Matrix-Vector multiplication is define as C_{k} = sum_{l} A_{kl}*B_{l} i.e (kl,l->k). so you should do torch.einsum('ijkl, ijl -> ijk', A, B) as shown by @hpaulj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the options with `numpy`. (I don't have `torch`)

```
In [120]: A = np.random.random((64, 128, 10, 10))
     ...: B = np.random.random((64, 128, 10))
```

Your iterative reference case:

```
In [122]: C = np.zeros((64,128,10))
     ...: # C should have shape: (64, 128, 10)
     ...: for i in range(0, 64):
     ...:    for j in range(0, 128):
     ...:        C[i,j] = np.matmul(A[i,j], B[i,j])
     ...:
```

`matmul` with full broadcasting:

```
In [123]: D  = np.matmul(A, B[:,:,:,None])
In [125]: C.shape
Out[125]: (64, 128, 10)
In [126]: D.shape            # D has an extra size 1 dimension
Out[126]: (64, 128, 10, 1)
In [127]: np.allclose(C,D[...,0])    # or use squeeze
Out[127]: True
```

The `einsum` equivalent:

```
In [128]: E = np.einsum('ijkl,ijl->ijk', A, B)
In [129]: np.allclose(C,E)
Out[129]: True
```